# Pass object to browser with window.open in Edge

Tags: xmldocument, window.open, microsoft-edge

In case of **Edge** browser say Browser One, passing a custom argument to second Browser.
if I pass a string it is available in the second window. But, if I pass an object (say XMLDocument) in the second window, I could not serialzetoString.

```
var myWin = window.open(...);
myWin.customArg = 'string parameter'  // Works
myWin.customArg = xmlObject  // Doesnt Work
```

in the second window,

```
new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlDoc)
```

throws xml parser exception.

Can any one help in resolving this? 
Same code works fine for Chrome.

Edit - Sample code of Parent Window is here -

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function OpenWindow()
        {
            var objXML = '<SelectedCharts><Chart ColumnNo="1" ChartName="E0PK" GroupName="test" OrderNo="1" /></SelectedCharts>';
            var xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(objXML,'text/xml');
            var dialog = window.open("Child_Window.htm", "title", "width=550px, height= 350px,left=100,top=100,menubar=no,status=no,toolbar=no");
            dialog.dialogArguments = xmlDoc ;
            dialog.opener = window;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <span>Passing an XML Object to the child window:</span>
    <input type="button" value="Open Popup" onclick="OpenWindow()" />
</body>
</html>
```

And the sample code of Child window is here -

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onBodyLoad()
        {
            alert(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(window.dialogArguments));
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="onBodyLoad()">
    <span>This is child window.</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share a *working* example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippet shown in the question works fine for Chrome browser. And to pass the context to another window in case of Edge browser, follow the below method.

declare a global variable and set it in the parent window 
And, access the varable in the child window using window.opener.

And sample code is provided in [Pass custom arguments to window.open in case of Edge browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947586/)