# Pass custom arguments to window.open in case of Edge browser

Tags: parameters, window.open, microsoft-edge

From a parent window say A, trying to open another window - ChildWindow.htm using window.open. I am unable to pass string value from A.

```
var dialog = window.open("Child_Window.htm?", "title", "width=550px, height= 350px,left=100,top=100,menubar=no,status=no,toolbar=no");
dialog.MyVariable = "some string value";
dialog.opener = window;
```

In Child window, I get

```
window.MyVariable
```

as undefined

Comment: I have got a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippet shown in the question works fine for Chrome browser. And to pass the context to another window in case of Edge browser, follow the below method.

declare a global variable in the parent window

```
var myVariable; 
dialog = window.open("Child_Window.htm", "title", "width=550px, height= 350px,left=100,top=100,menubar=no,status=no,toolbar=no");
```

Set the variable

```
myVariable = "Sample String Value";
```

And, access the varable in the child window using window.opener, like -

```
var myVar = window.opener.myVariable;
```